# How to find the index of a li tag having a specific tag inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>
<span>text</span>
</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
```

I need to get the index of the li tag having the `<span>` as a child. I tried something like this

```
 var page_no=$('.pagination');
        if(page_no.find('span').length>0)
        {
            var parent1=$(this).parent('li');
            var index=page_no.index(parent1);
            alert(index);
        }
```

but give me a -1 output!.
Please help !!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)/[:has-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
var index = $('ul.pagination li').has('span').index();
var index = $('ul.pagination li:has(span)').index();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3vZs4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/2VhTr/)

```
$('.pagination li').each(function(index){
    if($(this).has("span").length > 0){
    alert(index)
    }

});
```